Redirect website endpoints locally
Whenever I click a link that hits this endpoint:

youtube.com/shorts/{video_id}

I'd like my browser to instead end up at

youtube.com/watch/{video_id}

(Since /shorts/ is grotesquely horrible on desktop)
Are there any good ways to achieve this?
I'm thinking that I could maybe write a Chrome extension to achieve that. But would definitely prefer a cleaner solution
Clarification to appease bot
Current Scenario:

I'm sent a link (https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uDPsGIFw4vc)
I click the link
My browser opens https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uDPsGIFw4vc

New Scenario:

I'm sent a link (https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uDPsGIFw4vc)
I click the link
My browser opens https://www.youtube.com/watch/uDPsGIFw4vc


there is a chrome extension existent,
Youtube shorts Block.
Had tried it for few scenarios and it works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

the references to the search was in a reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/Vanced/comments/osn1nn/suggestion_watch_shorts_as_regular_videos/)

Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.
